# JavaScript delete operator and Object.create() method

Tags: javascript, object, delete-operator, object-create

I am trying to remove a property from an `Person` object like this:

```js
const Person = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}

console.log(Person.firstname);
// Output: "John"

delete Person.firstname;

console.log(Person.firstname);
// Output: undefined
```

When I am using this `delete` operator is working fine and `Person.firstname` log is showing as `undefined` as expected. But when I create a new object using this `Person` object using `Object.create()` method like this:

```js
const Person = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}

const Person2 = Object.create(Person);

console.log(Person2.firstname);
// Output: "John"

delete Person2.firstname;

console.log(Person2.firstname);
// expected output: undefined
// actual output: "John"
```

You can see `Person2.firstname` is returning "John" in the end, when I was expecting it to work same way as done in the first snippet and return `undefined`.

So, my questions here are:

- Why is `delete Person2.firstname` not working?
- Also, how can we delete `firstname` property from the `Person2` object?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` will *only* successfully remove a property from an object if the property to be deleted is an own non-configurable property. Here, your `Person2` does *not* have an own property of `firstname`, so `delete Person2.firstname` doesn't work. The property exists on the internal prototype of `Person2`, but not on `Person2` itself.

To delete the property, you'll have to call `delete` with the prototype object:

```
delete Person.firstname;
```

```js
const Person = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}
const Person2 = Object.create(Person);
delete Person.firstname;
console.log(Person2);
```

or, if you don't already have a reference to it, use `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```
delete Object.getPrototypeOf(Person2).firstname;
```

```js
const Person = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}

const Person2 = Object.create(Person);
delete Object.getPrototypeOf(Person2).firstname;
console.log(Person2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a shallow copy  and you want to do deep copy

tht can be achieved by something like

```js
const Person = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}



const Person2 = Object.assign({},Person);

console.log(Person2.firstname);
// Output: "John"

delete Person2.firstname;

console.log(Person2.firstname);
// expected output: undefined
// actual output: "undefined"
console.log(Person2.lastname)
```

[this will give you more clarity on shallow and deep copy](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd/)